Sculpting Brush Falloff Adjustment
I'm using the mask brush, tho this is an issue with any other as far as I can see. I've selected the linear falloff and what I expected was a mask like the B line but instead I'm getting the A line

From what I see in other brushes, it's like the brushes have an internal radius, about 75% of the area, where the brush is applied 100% and the falloff setting only affects the way that inner circle connects to the outer one, but I don't see any setting that would control that and changing the radius doesn't seem to affect it.
Is there some setting I have to change to make it so what I get is B?

I don't know how to solve it, but I think it's because the brush is round, so there is what is in front, summing with what's in the middle, summing with what's behind. You need a very pointy falloff to compensate for this.

A Custom Falloff should help to define the darkest part of the line and the falloff to the edge.   I will try to explain why.
I will include my Blendfile, but in case you want to reproduce the result, here are my settings, Brush menu: Normal Radius 0.010, Hardness 0.010, and Stroke menu:  Line, Spacing 5%, AdjustStrength for Spacing is turned off.
Controlling the Strength value controls both the opacity and inner stroke width, and is limited by the Radius value. To visualize this, go to the Display Cursor menu.
When the eye icons are turned off we see only Strength and Radius, and notice if we put Strength up to 100% it will occupy the entire total area of the brush (Radius), leaving no room for a gradient falloff.


Since Strength controls both the inner circle and a value of brush opacity at the same time.     A Strength value of 1.00 means that it is 100% opacity and occupies 100% of the Radius.
When we switch the display settings, and Falloff Opacity is turned on, you will see a closer approximation actual Falloff curve.
For the sake of providing an example only, I wondered:
what if we want 100% brush Strength opacity value but occupy 25% of the Radius?  As I mentioned before, we can't set the strength to 100% because that will give us an opaque circle that stretches all the way to the outer radius.  The only way we can do this is with precision to set a custom falloff:



We've created a 'gate' for our 100% Strength value that holds it to a quarter of the total Radius of the brush.  It isn't what we want- but now  all we have to do is set our falloff starting from that 0.25 point.
The falloff should be more steep than the linear, sharper or sharp settings because after all, the brush circles will overlap, depending on the Spacing percentage.
If you want a more gradual falloff, just make the curve slightly more gentle and increase the Radius value. Continuing with the example, with one point 0,1.0 and the next point at 0.25, 1.0, To roll-off, a middle point of 0.33, 0.33 between the last point at 1.0, 0 seems to work well to generate the gradient well.
Now, by pressing the F short cut, or refining the Custom Falloff we should be able to make the whole line thinner and keep the gradient effect.


Blender 3.5


I guess the pic doesn't show it very well but what I want is a constant gradient between the center of the brush and the outside of the stroke, not a thin line at full opacity in the middle. I'm on blender 3.5.1, is yours a newer version? I've tried changing the setting in the opacity sliders and a custom falloff but it doesn't seem to change anything on my version

Quite possible that another setting like 'Spacing' would affect this as well, so I've included my Blender 3.5 file and made some changes to my answer.
